# How to perform a standard deviation stretch on a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, erdas-imagine

Is there a way to perform a (2) standard deviations stretch on a raster image in QGIS 2.2?

I have found the raster styles menu, but the help says there is no help in my language (English) and whilst there is a mean +- standard deviation option, changing this (and pressing apply) seems to have no effect. Ideally I would like to set up such a stretch as standard for rasters (and i am fairly sure how to do this once I work out the setting needed) to try and replicate the standard stretch functionality found in ERDAS.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select "Mean +/- standard deviation", choose 2.0 in the value. Than press load, and press apply. If you don’t press load QGIS doesn’t calculate the new Min - Max values.